# android: Is it possible to put multiple layouts in listview items

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview

hi I want to use a listview (probably) is it possible to fill each entry with say two buttons two text areas, and have them laid out with realtive or linear layouts?

I have used a scroll view with layout inflator to achieve this at the moment, but I'm thinking listview would be better maybe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes you can. you need to use a custom list view for that. making an activity by adding a listview in it and then referencing another xml to that listview using an AAdapter so that every element of the listview has the layout of the second xml file. this [tutorial](http://www.softwarepassion.com/android-series-custom-listview-items-and-adapters/) should help you understand the idea.

Comment: thanks for the tutorial link. I'm gonna take a look through it. unlikely to be today though as my head is in androidoverload mode...

Comment: even though the process looks a little elaborate, once you understand it, it is actually a very simple thing to implement.

Comment: That tutorial totally sort me out, so much better now thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can place any widgets for the particular List Item for your listview.

For defining that kind of ListView, you have to define a **custom adapter**, follow the below steps:

1. Define a one row file for the list item, say for example, RelativeLayout with 2-3 TextViews.
2. Define a class by extending `BaseAdapter`.
3. Inflate the XML and do display operations inside the `getView()` method of this class.
4. Set this adapter to the ListView.