# Displaying multiple data in a list view

Tags: java, android, listview, for-loop

Hi i am new to android development, and i wanted to ask if its possible to display more than one name in a list view coming from a database?
for example

I want two information displayed, 
One will be a medication Name and the second info will be the number of how many required.

Paracetamol, Req: 10.

Anadol, Req: 6.

and so on.

furthermore the information coming from the database is as follows:

Medication Name.
Maximum No of Stock.
Current No of Stock.

And the list should display the name and the difference between (Max - Current).

is this possible? thank you for you help in advance :)

Comment: you should take a look at this discussion http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10091986/android-is-it-possible-to-put-multiple-layouts-in-listview-items/10092056#10092056

Answer (score 0):

Yes

You need to build a custom list in order to do this. Take a look at this great tutorial to learn more about this. http://www.vogella.de/articles/AndroidListView/article.html

Answer (score 0):

yes, It is definitely  possible. If you have a `CursorAdapter`, then you just need to use `android.R.two_line_list_item.xml` which makes things very easy . The best example is here :http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ListActivity.html

To use it with an `ArrayAdapter`, you will need to go **custom**. I could have given a sample code but you will find many samples from google, for example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2109271/can-any-one-provide-me-example-of-two-line-list-item-in-android)